# Showing that any harmonic tempered distribution is a polynomial.

Tags: distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

In PDE basic theory by the author Taylor I can't understand two facts:

Prop 1. If $u\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is supported by $\left\{0\right\}$, then there exists $k$ and complex numbers $a_\alpha$ such that
\begin{align}
u=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k} a_\alpha D^\alpha \delta
\end{align}

Prop 2. Suppose $u\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ satisfies $\Delta u=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $u$ is a polynomial in $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$.
Proof.  $|\xi|^2\widehat{u}=0$ in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ implies that $\text{supp}\widehat{u}\subset \left\{0\right\}$. By prop 1, \begin{align}
u=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k} a_\alpha D^\alpha \delta
\end{align}

**Question 1**. Why  $\text{supp} \widehat{u}\subset \left\{0\right\}$?

**Question 2**. Why $u=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k} a_\alpha D^\alpha \delta$ implies that $u$ is a polynomial in $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$?